# Angular ng-select bug in Chrome Windows when using tab navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There seems to be a weird bug when selecting values in Chrome on Windows using the keyboard only.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.d = '';
    $scope.options = [1,2,3];
    $scope.d2 = '';
    $scope.options2 = [1,2,3];
}

<input><br>
<select ng-options="d for d in options" ng-model="d"></select><br>
<select ng-options="d for d in options2" ng-model="d2"></select><br>
<input>
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DrTCZ/4/

Steps to replicate:

1. Click on first text field
2. Press tab
3. Using the keyboard, select 2
4. Press tab
5. Using the keyboard, select 2

Notice the value of the first dropdown.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I do not see any problems. Please specify which platform you are experiencing the problem on and a screenshot or a better description of the behavior you see.

Comment: Windows Chrome. The bug is definitely there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, seems like the bug, when 1st combo selected `2` and moved to second one, the change distributes on 1st as well.

Generally (I think in most cases) we have start element, like:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.options = [1,2,3];
     $scope.d  = $scope.options[0];

    $scope.options2 = [1,2,3];
    $scope.d2 = $scope.options2[0];    
}
```

In this case this issue is gone.

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrTCZ/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: Works. Will resort to this if I must.